# SubQuery within SUM CASE AND IN Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query blow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       'CONTRACT',
       CO.OBJID,
       CO.ORDERNUMBER
       (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'BGL'
                        THEN TG.QUANTITY
                        ELSE 0 END) AS Cartons,
               SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'CT'
                        THEN TG.QUANTITY
                        ELSE 0 END) AS Boxes,
               SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'PL'
                        THEN TG.QUANTITY
                        ELSE 0 END) AS Trailer
        FROM   GOODS TG,
               XTYPE CT 
        WHERE  TG.ORDERID = CO.OBJID 
        AND    TG.CONTOBJECTID = CT.OBJID 
        AND    CT.SHORTNAME IN ('BGL', 'CT', 'PL')
       ) 
FROM   XCUSTORDER CO,
       XEDIPARTNER EP
WHERE  CIP.CUSTOID = CO.OBJECTID 
AND    CO.EDIPARTNER_OBJECTID = EP.OBJECTID
AND    EP.ILNNUMBER = 'NASA'
```

The query is not working how can I achive the result I need. I dont want to run a diffrent select for each of the Cartons, Boxes and Trailer

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: First, edit your question and define clearly "not working". We wont spent our time scrutinizing your query to understand if you have a Syntax mistake leading to a ORA error, or if the data returned doesnt suit your needs.

Comment: Missing comma after `CO.ORDERNUMBER`. Subquery returns three values, so you probably get `ORA-00913 too many values`. You need three subqueries or CTE or change the whole query to `left join` version.

Comment: OP, you can simply add comma after `CO.ORDERNUMBER` in the select list but I don't think it will work after doing that also. I am not sure but you can do it in the following way.

Comment: @ThomasG Sorry for the errors. There is no ORA error, when the query was executed in my system. I just anonymize some part of code that are not allowed in the public domain.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: if you want to do all in single query. You have to query separately for each column as below. I am not sure that it will work because it's not tested but I am sure it will give you good idea. You are joining with `CIP.CUSTOID` but the table with `CIP` alias is not mentioned anywhere in the query so I did `EP` in the second query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       'CONTRACT',
       CO.OBJID,
       CO.ORDERNUMBER,
       (SELECT SUM(TG.QUANTITY)
        FROM   GOODS TG,
               XTYPE CT 
        WHERE  TG.ORDERID = CO.OBJID 
        AND    TG.CONTOBJECTID = CT.OBJID 
        AND    CT.SHORTNAME IN ('BGL')) AS Cartons,

        (SELECT SUM(TG.QUANTITY)
        FROM   GOODS TG,
               XTYPE CT 
        WHERE  TG.ORDERID = CO.OBJID 
        AND    TG.CONTOBJECTID = CT.OBJID 
        AND    CT.SHORTNAME IN ('CT')) AS Boxes,

        (SELECT SUM(TG.QUANTITY)
        FROM   GOODS TG,
               XTYPE CT 
        WHERE  TG.ORDERID = CO.OBJID 
        AND    TG.CONTOBJECTID = CT.OBJID 
        AND    CT.SHORTNAME IN ('PL')) AS Trailer
FROM   XCUSTORDER CO,
       XEDIPARTNER EP
WHERE  CIP.CUSTOID = CO.OBJECTID 
AND    CO.EDIPARTNER_OBJECTID = EP.OBJECTID
AND    EP.ILNNUMBER = 'NASA'
```

You can change your query in the following way:

```
SELECT
    'CONTRACT',
    CO.OBJID,
    CO.ORDERNUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'BGL'
            THEN TG.QUANTITY
            ELSE 0 END) AS Cartons,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'CT'
            THEN TG.QUANTITY
            ELSE 0 END) AS Boxes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CT.SHORTNAME = 'PL'
            THEN TG.QUANTITY
            ELSE 0 END) AS Trailer
FROM XCUSTORDER CO
INNER JOIN XEDIPARTNER EP ON  EP.CUSTOID = CO.OBJECTID 
    AND CO.EDIPARTNER_OBJECTID = EP.OBJECTID
    AND EP.ILNNUMBER = 'NASA'
LEFT JOIN GOODS TG ON TG.ORDERID = CO.OBJID
LEFT JOIN XTYPE CT ON TG.CONTOBJECTID = CT.OBJID
    AND CT.SHORTNAME IN ('BGL', 'CT', 'PL')
GROUP BY CO.OBJID,
    CO.ORDERNUMBER
```

Comment: HI Suraz. Thanks for the suggestion. I think your second query or answer is what I have missed.

Comment: Sorry was too fast.. Your query is not working.. demanding group by

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding me, it's added in the second query.